# With Facebook Open Graph, is there some way to specify separate OG tags for Like vs. Share?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

This is a really basic (potentially very dumb) question but I can't find an answer scouring the Facebook developer site.

Say your website's main page is www.example.com.  And you have a subpage on the site at www.example.com/specific-page.php

On specific-page.php, I'd like to have two buttons next to each other:

1. A Facebook Like button that when clicked, likes my main domain (www.example.com).
2. A Facebook Share button that when clicked, shares specific-page.php

Obviously I'd have OG meta tags on specific-page.php (like those below) but both the Share and Like buttons are using that info, so it seems you can't have the Like be attributed to the primary domain and the Share to the specific page's info.

In other words, if the Like button count on www.example.com's homepage showed 143 likes and then someone on specific-page.php clicked Like, I'd want that homepage number to now be 144.

```
<meta property="og:image"content="http://www.example.com/images/facebookthumb.png" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Example" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/specific-page.php" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Example"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Example.com is an exemplary site." />
```

So I guess my ultimate question is:  Is there some way to specify separate OG tags for Like vs. Share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. Earlier, there was an option to use the `FB.ui` feed dialog for sharing with custom parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

> As of April 18, 2017, the following parameters are no longer supported
>   by Graph API versions 2.9 and higher. For versions 2.8 and lower, the
>   parameters will continue working until July 17, 2017.

Comment: So by "Earlier, there was an option", are you saying it can no longer be used, or will it be completely deprecated soon?  In reading thru the link you sent (thank you), seems like just a few properties will be deprecated soon, but I could be misunderstanding.

Comment: i will add that info to my answer. well, it´s just a quote from the docs.